# Javascript function to merge / combine two URLSearchParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wondering what is the best **most efficient** code in Javascript to merge two URLSearchParams, but where one of them has higher priority, let me explain with two examples.

```
const oldParams = 'foo=one&coo=two'
const newParams = 'roo=three&moo=four'
```

`urlCombine(oldParams, newParams)` returns `foo=one&coo=two&roo=three&moo=four`

**So far so good**, but let's say we also want to give `newParams` higher priority so that if the same `key` exist in both `newParams` and `oldParams` the return value should always use the `value` of `newParams`, for example.

```
const oldParams = 'foo=one&coo=two'
const newParams = 'coo=three&foo=four'
```

`urlCombine(oldParams, newParams)` returns `foo=four&coo=three`

Comment: So you want a formula that will compare the values of the same keys and understand if it's greater or smaller. If it's greater it will replace the value if not keep the same?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by efficiency for this question? Have you tried something and determined that it's not efficient enough?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou No the value key pair of `newParams` should always replace the value key pair of `oldParams` if the key exist in both variables.

Comment: @BenStephens anything concise is okay, I am working on my own solution, but halfway in, I realise that it probably is not the best way to solve this problem, it is taking 20+ lines already, so I thought of asking this question here, also since (I believe) this particular question has not been asked before.

Comment: Just for fun (and because you said concise), here's a one line version based on @Thomas's answer: `const merge_params = (params1, params2) => [...(new URLSearchParams(params2)).entries()].reduce((a, [key, val]) => (a.set(key, val), a), new URLSearchParams(params1)).toString();`

Comment: Haha cool, in my world short = efficient, awesome thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [URLSearchParams](https://mdn.io/URLSearchParams) to parse the strings into key-value pairs and then combine them.

```js
const oldParams = 'foo=one&coo=two'
const newParams1 = 'roo=three&moo=four'
const newParams2 = 'coo=three&foo=four'

function urlCombine(a,b,overwrite=false){
  a = new URLSearchParams(a);
  const fn = overwrite ? a.set : a.append;
  for(let [key, value] of new URLSearchParams(b)){
    fn.call(a, key, value);
  }
  return a.toString();
}

console.log(urlCombine(oldParams, newParams1));
console.log(urlCombine(oldParams, newParams2, false));
console.log(urlCombine(oldParams, newParams2, true));
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but I got a result where it reversed the order of the key value pairs of `newParams`? I got this when running the snippet straight into the console. `foo=one&coo=two&three=roo&four=moo`

Comment: @Alien13 Yes, tried to be smart with forEach but made a mistake. Also added the option to chose whether you want to append or overwrite the old values.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas, your updated code has passed my very simple and manual QA test, I will reward you, congrats!